# Creating a Clustered Bar chart with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is extremely trivial, so I apologize!

I'm just getting into matplotlib and pandas and I think I'm over complicating it...
I'm trying to create a clustered bar chart (like the one below).

[image: Clustered Bar Chart]

The dataframe I a working with is structured like this:

[image: Data Structure]

I want to create a clustered bar chart where the x-axis is days of the week (df['Days of Week']), the y axis is count, and the categories of what is being counted are Type A and Type B (determined by df['Type']).

From the googling I am doing, my code is long and complicated... but I feel like this is easier than I'm making it...

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_df = (df.groupby('Days of Week')['Type']
            .value_counts()
            .unstack()
         )

new_df.plot.bar()
```